# Django ORM query GROUP BY multiple columns combined by MAX

Tags: python, mysql, orm, django-models

I am using Django with MySQL. I have a model similar to the following:

```
class MM(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField()
    b = models.IntegerField()
    c = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I have multiple rows that `a` is equal to `b`, and I want to perform the following SQL query:

```
SELECT a, b, MAX(c) AS max FROM MM GROUP BY b, a;
```

How can this be done with Django ORM? I have tried different approaches using annotations, but now luck so far.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13):

I think you can do something like:

```
MM.objects.all().values('b', 'a').annotate(max=Max('c'))
```

Note that you need to import something to use Max: `from django.db.models import Max`

`values('b', 'a')` will give `GROUP BY b, a` and `annotate(...)` will compute the MAX in your query.

Comment: FYI the `all()` is redundant and is not required.

Comment: Just to formalise, here's the [documentation link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#values) "...the original results are grouped according to the unique combinations of the fields specified in the values() clause."

Answer (score 3):

You can try this also

```
from django.db.models import Max

mm_list=MM.objects.all().values('b','a').annotate(max=Max('c'))
for mm in mm_list:
    a=mm['a']
    b=mm['b']
    max=mm['max']
```

Answer (score 1):

Sum a field group by two fields.

```
from django.db.models import Sum
```

SQL

```
select caja_tipo_id, tipo_movimiento, sum(monto) from config_caja group by caja_tipo_id, tipo_movimiento
```

Django

```
objs = Caja.objects.values('caja_tipo__nombre','tipo_movimiento').order_by().annotate(total=Sum('monto'))
```