# Annotate with a filtered related object set

Tags: python, django

So I have a `SensorType` model, which has a collection of `SensorReading` objects as part of a `sensorreading_set` (i.e., the sensor type has many sensor readings). I want to annotate the sensor types to give me the sensor reading with the max id. To wit:

```
sensor_types = SensorType.objects.annotate(
                newest_reading_id=Max('sensorreading__id'))
```

This works fantastically, but there's a catch. Sensor Readings have another foreign key, `Device`. What I really want is the highest sensor reading id for a given sensor type **for a given device.** Is it possible to have the annotation refer to a subset of sensor readings that basically amounts to `SensorReading.objects.filter(device=device)`?

Comment: Uhh, can't you just chain those two? `SensorReading.objects.filter(device=device).annotate(newest_reading_id=Max('sensorreading__id'))`?

Comment: You're forgetting the Sensor Type. I need to get the max id sensor reading for each type, not the max for every sensor reading, so I can't simply chain using the SensorReading resource.

Comment: Ahh, you're right! I conflated your models, didn't I? You probably need a [Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) for this kind of query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering works perfectly fine with related objects, and annotations work perfectly fine with those filters. What you need to do is:

```
from django.db.models import Max

SensorType.objects.filter(sensorreading__device=device) \
                  .annotate(newest_reading_id=Max('sensorreading__id'))
```

Note that the order of function calls matters. Using `filter` before `annotate` will only annotate on the filtered set, using `annotate` before `filter` will annotate on the complete set, and then filter. Also, when filtering on related objects, keep in mind that `filter(sensorreading__x=x, sensorreading__y=y)` will filter for sensorreadings where all conditions are true, while `.filter(sensorreading__x=x).filter(sensorreading__y=y)` will filter for sensorreadings where either one of these conditions is true.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **.extra for these type of Queries in Django:**

Like this:

```
SensorType.objects.extra(
     select={
       "newest_reading_id": "SELECT MAX(id) FROM sensorreading WHERE sensorreading.sensortype_id = sensortype.id AND sensorreading.device_id=%s",
     },
     select_params = [device.id]
)
```

You can read more about .extra here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to GROUP_BY on two fields, `device_id` and `sensortype_id`. This can be done using:

```
SensorReading.objects.all().values('device_id', 'sensortype_id').annotate(max=Max('id'))
```

I didn't tried it; it was taken from 2 different answers in SO, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16547896/931303) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2918722/931303).