# Filtering sequences of events in django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

My django app stores the actions that players do during a game. One of the models is called *Event*, and it contains a list of all actions by players. It has the following 4 columns: *game_id, player_name, action, turn*. Turn is the number of the turn in which the action takes place.

Now I want to count how often players behave in certain patterns. For example, I want to know how often a player takes decision A in turn 2 and that same player takes decision B in turn 3. I'm breaking my head over how I can do this. Can someone help?

**Note:** Ideally the queries should be efficient, bearing in mind that some related queries are following. For example, after the above query I would want to know how often a player takes decision C in turn 4, after doing A and B in turns 2 and 3. (The goal is to predict the likelihood of each action, given the actions in the past.)

Comment: Any efforts? You may try [GROUP BY on multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37483884/django-orm-group-by-multiple-columns)

Comment: With a GROUP BY I could do things like count the number of actions each player performed in each turn, but I don't see how I can use it to do what I described.